# Send files from vb.NET client to c++ server

Tags: c++, vb.net

What's the best way to do this without using FTP?

The client would need to be able to communicate with the server for several simple tasks, such as checking if the file on the client is different from the file on the server. Or issue a "create folder" command. And of course the file transfer itself.

Can this be done using sockets maybe? I could send messages to the server like this:

```
"checkfileMD5,somefolder/blabla.txt,*MD5HASH*"
```

And then have the server return 1 or 0 based on whether or not the file MD5 the client sent is the same as what resides on the server.

```
"createfolder,somefolder/,*NewFolderName*"
```

Which would create `somefolder/NewFolderName` on the server.

But is this the best solution, can files even be transfered over sockets (and if so, how?), and do sockets even work cross-platform?

Comment: The entire point of sockets is that they are crossplatform. You do not need to know that the server is written in C++. Think about the internet: you have no idea what language the server is written in or what OS is running on the server, but you can visit any website from any computer just fine.

Comment: You need to read a primer on network programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define what "best" means.  To me, best means getting the job done without having to write a lot of new code.  How about uploading the file as a form using POST to an HTTP server?  Arguments would be authorization information and pathname of file.  The server would be listening on port 80 but doesn't ever need to return a webpage!  It could just return a standard HTTP code for success or an error if there is a problem.  This way the only thing you have to provide is the CGI to check the request and store the file.